# Loading SketchUp Models in SceneKit for ARKit App

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have a scene.scn file which contains a car.dae model. Here is the image:

[image]

I have the following code to load the scene.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/scene.scn")!

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }
```

I do not see the car being loading in the scene. Any ideas?

Comment: How big is the car? If you're looking in the Xcode scene editor where you took your screenshot, there should be bounding box info in the inspector. Also, you probably want to reorient your model so that Y is up.

Comment: I can get the car to be displayed. I removed the camera and now it works! The other problem is that the car moves with the user movement. I want the car to be fixed at one location so I can move around and look at the car in different angles.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think it has something to do with my model because other scn files work.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was the size. I adjusted the scale of the model and made is much small and then it started to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

The following workflow produces repeatable results for me when exporting a 3D model from SketchUp Make 2017 (I use the *Simple Template - Meters* for drawing) to Xcode 9.0:

1. In Xcode, create a SceneKit asset catalog: Create an assets catalog and change the extension to `.scnassets` before saving.
2. In Xcode, in the asset catalog Settings, ensure that *Always use the Y-up axis* is **not** checked. This setting is buggy; while it works during runtime, it isn't taken into account by the Scene Editor.
3. In SketchUp, export the model using *Export 3D Model...* and select the file format *COLLADA File (*.dae)*. Export it to the `.scnassets` folder of the asset catalog (or a subfolder thereof).

   **Hint:** If you export somewhere else, use the Finder to copy or move the files. Don't drag-and-drop the exported model to Xcode, as it would only create a reference to the model and you would lose the textures on the way, as they are referenced in the `.dae` file by a relative path.
4. In Xcode, create a SceneKit Scene File: First, select the project and create a *New file* with the template *SceneKit Scene File* there; Save it in the `.scnassets` folder; Then *delete* the file (*Remove reference*) from your project, so that it is referenced only in the `.scnassets` folder.

   **Hint:** You can't create a `.scn` file directly in the asset catalog, as the *New file* feature creates an empty file that the Scene Editor won't recognize, even if you rename it with the `.scn` extension.
5. Embed the `.dae` file in the scene and fix the axes:

   a. Open the `.scn` file.

   b. Drag-and-drop the `.dae` file to the scene. This creates a reference to the model. Ensure that the reference to the model is selected.

   c. In the *Node Inspector*, under *Transforms*, select the *Editing space*: ***Local***.

   d. Set the local *Position* to *x*: *0*, *y*: *0*, *z*: *0* (or whatever position is needed).

   e. Set the local *Euler* angles to *x*: *-90*, *y*: *0*, z: *0*. Now, the object is oriented as expected, e.g. its front is displayed when the point of view *Front* is selected in the toolbar at the bottom of the scene editor.

   f. Set the local *Scale* to *x*: *0.0254*, *y*: *0.0254*, *z*: *0.0254*. I assume that the `.dae` file import expects sizes in inches.

   g. Still in the *Node Inspector*, under *Transforms*, select the *Editing space*: ***World***. Check the size of the *Bounding Box*. I assume that meters are used as measurement unit here. Save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

There's a flag in Xcode's scnassets inspector to set which axis is "up". In SceneKit, Y is up. IIRC SketchUp uses Z up by default.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: I found for all the collada (dae) models created by SketchUp  you need to  adjust the Euler x-axis to -90 in the scene editor 
In order to get the model the right way up when you load it.

Comment: Thanks! but how do you handle the size and x, y and z position. It is a complete mess. Any other recommendation

Comment: The app I’m using I can move, pivot left or right, scale the model manually by using standard  touch screen finger gestures. That’s the best way to manuiplate 3D models on a smart phone.